# How to use puppeteer in my website with a cdn

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, pdf-generation, puppeteer

Im trying to use Puppeteer for generate PDF files directly on my website.

My issue is i dont know how to add the required files to my website.

All the guides come with this line:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
```

But when i run the code i get this error: require is not defined

This is the code im trying to run:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
    await page.pdf({
    scale: 1,
    displayHeaderFooter: false,
    printBackground: true,
    landscape: false,
    path: 'hn.pdf',
    format: 'A4',
    width: 1200,
    height: 3500,
    margin: {
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0 
  }
  });
  await browser.close();
});
```

Normally when i want to use some online library it comes with a cdn link or you can download .js files and host them in my website, then i can use the code as i want.

But in this case, i searched in all ways, (around 2.5 hours) and i can't find anything.

Searching on google Puppeteer CDN i got this: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/puppeteer

But not sure how to use..
Thanks!

EDIT:

After some attemps, i created a .js file following the Browserify guide.
I added this code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
})();
```

And created a bundle of that code, which generated the following js script: https://puu.sh/AGF4U/46204f1b5c.js

Added the script to my website and trying now to execute this code:

```
(async () => {
  await page.goto('https://google.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4'});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Now im getting the following errors on console:
https://puu.sh/AGF6I/149fb9ec2b.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`puppeteer` is a `node.js` library, it cannot be run in a browser, on a web page. Think of it as of a program that need to be run on a computer/server.

To use it one needs to [install node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) first, then [install puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#installation), then create a script file with the program that makes a screenshot and finally run it from command prompt like

```
>node /path/to/script.js
```

Comment: Before wasm you are right. Now it can be.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use tool like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) in combination with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), which will create a bundle containing required modules and will compile your code for browsers.

EDIT: Since Webpack is little hard to set up consider using [Babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify).

Comment: Any idea how to use them? How i can create a bundle of this using those tools? (Never used)
Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer the link to Babelify includes tutorial on how to use it.

Comment: Thank you, im downloading the Babelify using: npm install --save-dev babelify@next @babel/core

When its downloaded i have to copy the code on somewhere editor?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-browserify it should help you get started.

Comment: Hello, thanks for posting the guide link. I was able to generate a bundle file using .js file. I should use on the source .js file the entire code? 
From my website how i should run the code?

Thanks!

Comment: I mean, what part of the code, i have to bundle? I generate a bundle from this code:
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
});

Then uploaded the file and removed that lines from the code, but still getting error. Any idea?

Comment: What are you using puppeteer for anyway ?

Comment: For generate PDF from url with many customization options like Puppeteer offers.

Comment: Updated post. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea @user3210641 ?? I'm stuck!

Comment: @user3210641 Alas, bundle manager won't help: `puppeteer` is strictly a server-side script because it uses **a whole Chromium browser(!)** underneath.

Comment: Hey @user3210641 so, were you able to figure out what puppeteer is and does?