# How to use recorded, puppeteer-like automation commands client side, e. g. as google chrome snippet in the browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, automation, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I would like to

- record some **browser automation** steps with the [Recorder](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/recorder) of google chrome dev tools
- generate puppeteer code from it
- copy the puppeteer code to a google chrome [Snippet](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/snippets)
- modify the code (e.g. to include extra for loops and conditional statements)
- run the snippet for the current browser session

However, **puppeteer** code is **server side** node.js code and not originally thought to be executed in a browser.

Instead of **server side** code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); // v20.7.4 or later

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: 'new'});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    //...
```

I would like to use some **client side** code like:

```
//load some puppeteer wrapper from cdn
fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/.../web-puppeteer.min.js')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => eval(text))

//connect to current browser session using that wrapper
const page = webPuppeteer.connectToCurrentPage(document);

//use previously recorded puppeteer commands for browser automation
//...


webPuppeteer.Locator.race([
        page.locator('::-p-aria(Search)'),
        page.locator('#APjFqb'),
        page.locator('::-p-xpath(//*[@id=\\"APjFqb\\"])'),
        page.locator(':scope >>> #APjFqb')
])
.fill('foo');
```

I found puppeteer-web. However, that project is archived and it seems that it would still need an extra server:

https://github.com/entrptaher/puppeteer-web

It also seems to be possible to start google chrome with the option `--remote-debugging-port`. However, that does not seem to make sense for my use case.

**=> How to use puppeteer commands client side for the current browser session?**

Of course not all the puppeteer commands would be supported. I only would need the ones related to the current page.

=> If that does not work with puppeteer code, is there another way to replay json that has been recorded with google chrome Recorder in client side Snippets?

=> Or is there a way to [edit the code in the recorder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBgzmqzp7ew) to include conditional statements etc? The steps of puppeteer replay do not seem to include a "loop" or "if" step.

**Related:**

[Connecting Browsers in Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096771/connecting-browsers-in-puppeteer)

https://github.com/entrptaher/puppeteer-web

[How to use puppeteer in my website with a cdn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892985/how-to-use-puppeteer-in-my-website-with-a-cdn)

[How to run Puppeteer code in any web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647694/how-to-run-puppeteer-code-in-any-web-browser)

[How to make Puppeteer work with a ReactJS application on the client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55031823/how-to-make-puppeteer-work-with-a-reactjs-application-on-the-client-side)

[Is There Any Client Side Web Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60162886/is-there-any-client-side-web-automation)

https://github.com/puppeteer/replay/blob/main/src/Schema.ts

https://github.com/puppeteer/replay/issues/730

Comment: If anyone would be able to control my browser when I visit their site/website, then it is a disaster. Unless you have the right permission to do so, you won't be able to run scripts this way.

Comment: I don't want to control your browser but only my browser, as I am already able to do with snippets. However, I would like to have a record option, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flows that has been recorded with chrome dev tools can be shown as json: Recorder => Show code => JSON.

[image]

Copy that JSON to vanilla JavaScript Snippet and write a custom implementation to process the flow as wanted.

For example, in order to process recorded button clicks:

```
var json = {
    "title": "foo",
    "steps": [
        {
            "type": "click",
            "target": "main",
            "selectors": [
              [
                "aria/ Ordner "
              ],
              [
                "#rcmbtn106"
              ],
              [
                "xpath///*[@id=\"rcmbtn106\"]"
              ],
              [
                "pierce/#rcmbtn106"
              ]
          ],
        }
    ]
};

for (var step in json.steps){
   if (step.type == 'click'){
      var selector = step.selectors[1][0];
      var targetElement = document.querySelector(selector);
      targetElement.click();
   }

  // implement other step types here

}
```